# troubleshooting: To run a flask file in jupyter lab

Tags: python, flask, jupyter-lab

[image]Below is the code in jupyter lab.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I create console for editor, I get nothing but three points(an ellipsis). When I type http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in the web browser, I get

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was
> unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
> there is an error in the application.

Below is the code of home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My First HTML Page in Jupyter Notebook</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <p>This is my first HTML page in Jupyter Notebook.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can it be caused by naming conflict? There are two "app"

> http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/stock.investing.decision.making/app/controllers/app.py

If I exit jupyter lab and restart it, it becomes fine. However, when I modify the content of app.py, it doesn't work again, then I have to restart jupyter lab. Why does this happen?

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to achieve running Flask inside jupyter instead of just as a script?

Comment: Have you tried using `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)`?

Comment: When I use app.run(host='0.0.0.1',port=5000) , it has the same effect.

Comment: To import MVC with the help of flask.

Comment: Try to use `0.0.0.0`

Comment: I uphold a picture, can you see it?

Comment: You are using `0.0.0.1`, but the correspondence to `localhost` is a `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. Whatever IP address I use, it is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255610/discussion-between-giba-and-steven).

Comment: Can you complete your question by putting the correspondent code to `home.html`?